# Foreign key not adding

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called courses and a table called modules.

The courses table has courseID, courseName, module1, module2.

The modules table has moduleID, moduleName.

I am trying to use this to add a foreign key, but an error says 'Cannot add foreign key constraints':

ALTER TABLE courses
ADD FOREIGN KEY (module1)
REFERENCES modules(moduleName)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the Designer view or Relation view to create the foreign key?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the primary key of `modules` is `moduleID`, your foreign key should be specified as

```
ALTER TABLE courses ADD FOREIGN KEY (module1) REFERENCES modules(moduleID)
```

and the type of the foreign key should be the same as that of the `modules` primary key.

Answer (score 1):

**Possiblities for this error occur**

1) The two key fields type and/or size is not an exact match.

2) One of the key field that you are trying to reference does not have an index and/or is not a primary key.

3) The foreign key name is a duplicate of an already existing key.

4) You have specified a cascade ON DELETE SET NULL, but the relevant key field is set to NOT NULL. You can fix this by either changing your cascade or setting the field to allow NULL values.

5) One of the fields in the relationship is part of a combination (composite) key and does not have it’s own individual index. Even though the field has an index as part of the composite key, you must create a separate index for only that key field in order to use it in a constraint.

6) You have a syntax error in your ALTER statement or you have mistyped one of the field names in the relationship.

7) The name of your foreign key exceeds the max length of 64 chars.

***Answer of your question:***

**Using Query**

```
ALTER TABLE courses ADD FOREIGN KEY (module1) REFERENCES modules(moduleName)
```

Here your syntax is correct.please check guidelines.

**Using GUI**

The form to put up the fk is under: table -> structure -> relationship overview

you need to setup index keys for the foreign keys

[image]